# jQuery div height calculate separately

Tags: jquery, height

I have this code:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('div.height').each(function() { maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());      }).height(maxHeight);
```

This code calculate each box even in length. But I want each box calculate separately in length. How can i do this?

**My HTML**

```
<div class="height"> 
     <div class="overlay height"></div>
     Content
</div>

<div class="height"> 
     <div class="overlay height"></div>
     Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure it out myself and this is the solution:

```
$('div.height').each(function() { 
    hParent = $(this).height();
    hChild = $(this).find('div.overlay').height();
    maxHeight = Math.max(hParent, hChild);    
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
    $(this).find('div.overlay').css("height",(maxHeight-72)+"px");  
});
```

Comment: If you are happy with that solution, you should mark your answer as "accepted" (the tick to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.height').each(function() { 
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());    
    $(this).height(maxHeight);  
})
```

Comment: In this case if $('div.height') returns an array of divs that are coincidentally increasing in heights then nothing will change on the page as maxHeight will always be the height of the current DOM element. Not sure that this is what he is asking for, but if it is you would iterate through all of the div.height elements after the initial loop finished and set the heights to maxHeight.

Comment: @Maanstraat did you remember to instantiate maxHeight? If you didn't then you are finding Math.max(Naan, number) which will not work.

Comment: Now he is doing something but every div is the same height. Screenshot: [link screen](http://www.dreamwire.nl/klanten/screen.jpg). So

Comment: When i first add your code he (the divs) weren't doing anything, now they do. But all div's are the same in height and are not calculating each box separately?

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you are setting everything to the CURRENT value of maxHeight instead of the FINAL value of maxHeight. If I understand that you intend to do correctly, then try separating it out as such:

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$('div.height').each(function() { maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height()); });

$('div.height').height(maxHeight);
```

This will apply the final maxHeight to all divs.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I thought .height was inside the .each function.